# Can't use redux actions inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, single-page-application

I have a component when loaded I want to dispatch a action, I have used mapDispatchToProps but I can't access the action in props, However it works in other components but whenever I call this function from componentDidMount it gives me Type error: no such function, I checked... there are no typos in my code and even then I can't seem to get it to work.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUserDetails } from "../../store/actions/usersActions";

export class UserDetails extends Component {
  state = {
    user: this.props.userDetails
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (prevProps.userDetails !== this.props.userDetails) {
      this.setState({
        user: this.props.userDetails
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    //this.props.getUserDetails(this.props.match.params.username);
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;

    return user ? (
      <div className="userDetails">
        <p>{user.username}</p>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className="userDetails" />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userDetails: state.user.userDetails
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getUserDetails: username => dispatch(getUserDetails(username))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserDetails);

componentDidMount() {
  19 |    console.log(this.props);
> 20 |    this.props.getUserDetails(this.props.match.params.username);
     | ^  21 |  }
  22 | 
  23 |  render() {
View compiled
commitLifeCycles
D:/Web Projects/min-social-media/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18109
  18106 |       !(instance.state === finishedWork.memoizedState) ? warning$1(false, 'Expected %s state to match memoized state before ' + 'componentDidMount. ' + 'This might either be because of a bug in React, or because ' + 'a component reassigns its own `this.props`. ' + 'Please file an issue.', getComponentName(finishedWork.type) || 'instance') : void 0;
  18107 |     }
  18108 |   }
> 18109 |   instance.componentDidMount();
        | ^  18110 |   stopPhaseTimer();
  18111 | } else {
  18112 |   var prevProps = finishedWork.elementType === finishedWork.type ? current$$1.memoizedProps : resolveDefaultProps(finishedWork.type, current$$1.memoizedProps);
```

Comment: you wrote `dispath`, looks like it should be `dispatch`

Comment: Nope, Still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Hmmm do you wanna make a codesandbox? We probably could help you resolve it if we see the rest of your code. With what you posted, there doesnt seem to be any issues.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo as long as it's *consistent* what you name the parameter doesn't matter

Comment: Give a [mcve], what's the full error.

Comment: The post is updated with the error

Comment: This seems more like a client-side issue. That said, I don't see how you are getting `Type error: not a function..` :/

Comment: This might not be the case but can check >> You are exporting the component itself  **export class UserDetails** and also the react-redux connected component as default export **export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserDetails)**

When you are importing this component make sure you are importing the connected  component which is the default exports

Comment: Yeah you were right I was importing it like {UserDetails} , Thanks for your help!